# Change title of Photo editing extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, photokit

Is it possible to change the title of the Photo Editing extension?

Currently it takes the name of the main app, but we want to tweak it slightly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't appear to be possible, though [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensibilityPG.pdf) doesn't explicitly state so. Two points are in conflict with each other, which might provide some insight.

> The displayed name of your app extension is provided by the extension target’s `CFBundleDisplayName` value, which you can edit in the extension’s Info.plist file. If you don’t provide a value for the `CFBundleDisplayName` key, your extension uses the name of its containing app, as it appears in the `CFBundleName` value.

This is not the case for Photo extensions — try it yourself. Changing either (or both) of these values in the extension's `Info.plist` does not change the name of the extension. The extension retains the name of the containing application. Then there's this:

> Embed no more than one Photo Editing extension for each media type (photo, video) in a containing app. The Photos app displays to the user, at most, one extension of each type from a given containing app.

While not explicit, this may indicate why you aren't currently able to change the name of a Photo extension. Because the containing application only presents a single Photo extension, maybe that's why the name can't be modified. Compare this to an app with a Today extension, where a containing app could present multiple extensions then requiring different names per extension.

Not a great reason, but it might provide insight.

Comment: I regard this as a bug. Instead of trying to justify it, we should be reporting it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Double click Project, select Target "extension" > Click Info

By setting name for "`Bundle display name (CFBundleDisplayName)`", the iOS share extension name can be changed to suit your need.

Using Xcode 7.2.1
Deployment Target 9.2